# JQuery - Collection Iteration

Tags: jquery

I am new to JQuery. I have a select html element. I am trying to understand how to iterate through the options in the select element. I know how to do it with traditional javascript as shown here:

```
for (i=0; i<mySelect.options.length; i++)
  alert(mySelect.options[i].value);
```

However, I'm trying to learn about JQuery more. Can someone show me the best way to iterate through a collection using JQuery?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off: IMHO it's great that you learn the non-jQuery way. Watch out that you don't slip into the thinking that everything better using jQuery.

To the problem: If you have a DOM reference `mySelect` to the `select` then you can get a jQuery object of the `option`s with `$(mySelect).find("option")`. The usual way to loop through them would be with jQuery's `each` method and an (anonymous) function:

```
$(mySelect).find("option").each(function() {
   alert(this.value);
})
```

Answer (score 9):

Depends on what you want to do.

- If you just want to iterative over the collection you could use [each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).
- If you want to iterate over the collection and apply a transform to each element (and get a new collection back) there is [map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/).
- If you just want to select a subset of your collection there is [grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#mySelect options").each(
    alert($(this).attr("value"));
)
```

Answer (score 1):

i believe you can use the each function for this. [See here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will get all input elements, and for [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) of them, print its index in the collection of elements (index) and its value to the log.

```
$(":input").each( function(index) { console.log(index + " " + this.value);})
```